# Machine learning: Training and Development Sets

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have a general question in machine learning:
There are Training Set, Development Set (to tune the parameters) and Test Set.

Is it possible to use SVM with the Training Set and various of features set, to get various of classifiers, and then test the classifiers on the Development Set, pick the classifier that gave the best result, and test it on the Test Set? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: I mean, will it be biased or is it a good built classifier?

Comment: Depends on how much you "abuse" it. You could overfit to your test set. Read about cross validation